# How to use a promise in do-while loop waiting a callback to be completed

Tags: javascript, promise, salesforce-lightning

I have a callback which waits for a response from a HTTP request which responds with the word "done" if a file is successfully uploaded and I make one request via a callback to upload a single file every time.

What I want is that when the response is "done", I want to upload multiple files with a `do-while` loop and I'm thinking of doing that with promises, but I don't really know how.

My code now:

```
var self = this;

let i = 0;
let fileInput = fileCmp.get("v.files");

do {

  // my callback
  self.uploadHelper(component, event, fileInput[i]);
  console.log("Uploading: " + fileInput[i].name);
  i++;

} while (i < fileInput.length);
```

The thing I want is to go to `i=1` (second file) only when I get the response "done" or something else from the call.

My callback which is called from `uploadHelper()`:

```
uploadChunk: function (component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId) {

  console.log('uploadChunk');
  var action = component.get("c.saveTheChunk");
  var chunk = fileContents.substring(fromPos, toPos);

  action.setParams({
    parentId: component.get("v.recordId"),
    fileName: file.name,
    base64Data: encodeURIComponent(chunk),
    contentType: file.type,
    fileId: attachId
  });

  action.setCallback(this, function (a) {

    console.log('uploadChunk: Callback');
    attachId = a.getReturnValue();

    fromPos = toPos;
    toPos = Math.min(fileContents.length, fromPos + this.CHUNK_SIZE);

    if (fromPos < toPos) {
      this.uploadChunk(component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId);
    } else {
      console.log('uploadChunk: done');
      component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
      // enabling the next button
      component.set("v.nextDisabled", false);
      component.set("v.uploadDisabled", true);
      component.set("v.clearDisabled", true);
      component.set("v.showToast", true);
      component.set("v.toastType", 'success');
      component.set("v.fileName", '');
      component.set("v.toastMessage", 'Upload Successful.');
    }
  });

  $A.getCallback(function () {
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  })();
}
```

Comment: Where are you passing a callback?

Comment: Btw that `self` is unneccessary. `this` can only be different between different functions.

Comment: The part you have labelled as `my callback` isn't actually a callback function.

Comment: @Andy yes it is an array.

Comment: @JonasWilms question updated.

Comment: Are you able to utilize the `async/await` "syntactic sugar" built on top of the promise mechanism? If so, that'd allow you to simply use synchronous flow controls such as do while loops.

Comment: @woozyking - `async/await` are, as you said, just sugar. You can do the same thing without it and just using promises.

Comment: @Adam certainly. Though it simplifies the usage of synchronous flow controls, as what OP wishes to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `uploadHelper` method not aync to achieve what you want.
Try to use the `async`, `await` and `Promise` objects to create a promis in your function (instead of a callback) and force it to happened synchronously.

It may look somthing like this:

```
// uploadHelper definiton, fit its to your code
const uploadHelper = (component, event, file) => {

    // Create the promise
    return new Promise(function(component, event, file) {
        // Do what you want to do
    })
}

// Use it
var self = this;
let i = 0;
let fileInput = fileCmp.get("v.files");
do{
    await self.uploadHelper(component, event, fileInput[i]).then(function() {
        console.log("Uploading: "+fileInput[i].name);
        i++;
    });
}
while(i< fileInput.length);
```

For further info try this links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

As your `uploadChunk` does an asynchronous task, it would make sense for the function to take a callback, that gets called back when the task is done (your code does not contain any callback yet). As callbacks are difficult to handle (especially with loops), it makes sense to wrap the callback into a Promise (that resolves when the callback gets called):

```
  uploadChunk: function (component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId) {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // the promise gets returned immeadiately, the "resolve" callback can be called to resolve it
      // ....
      action.setCallback(this, function (a) {
        //...
        resolve();
      });
    });
  },
```

Your `uploadHelper` could now return the promise returned back to the loop:

```
  uploadHelper(component, event, file) {
    //...
    return this.uploadChunk(component, file, /*...*/);
  }
```

Now that we have that, we can simply `await` that promise inside of an `async` function:

```
 (async () => { // arrow function to preserve "this"
    for(const file of files) { // Why do...while if you can use a for..of?
      await this.uploadChunk(component, event, file);
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the `while` loop, and simply `pop` an item off your `fileInput` array every time you use it. Cancel everything when the array becomes empty.

(You need to have a working callback function though...)

Comment: What? How is that related to the question? He could also use a for loop ... or ...

Comment: Using 'classic' loops of any kind with a promise/callback situation would be a little unusual!

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can do it with an auto run function :

```
            var self = this;
            let i = 0;
            let fileInput = fileCmp.get("v.files");
            do{
                // my callback
                (()=>{
                   self.uploadHelper(component, event, fileInput[i]);
                   console.log("Uploading: "+fileInput[i].name);
                   i++;
                })();
            }
            while(i< fileInput.length);
```